# Detecting Orphaned Users

Tags: sql-server

We have exported Microsoft SQL 2014 server and rebuilt master DB. Users are missing now, so we need to detect orphaned users.

We have found article:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/failover-clusters/troubleshoot-orphaned-users-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15#:%7E:text=%20Identify%20orphaned%20users%20in%20those%20environments%20with,are%20user%20SID%27s%20in%20the%20user...%20More%20

It says to use code in user database:

```
SELECT dp.type_desc, dp.SID, dp.name AS user_name  
FROM sys.database_principals AS dp  
LEFT JOIN sys.server_principals AS sp  
    ON dp.SID = sp.SID  
WHERE sp.SID IS NULL  
    AND authentication_type_desc = 'INSTANCE';
```

What is this user database? Where the code should be run to detect orphaned users? Now the server logins are missing. How to get same users as in original database?

Comment: Welcome to DBA.SE. Did you mean you exported the Microsoft SQL Server 2014 databaes and then rebuilt the SQL Server instance? Please add details to your question. if possible. (Hit [edit]).

Answer (score 0):

That might've been a little bit of poor wording on Microsoft's part but basically what they meant is run that query in the context of the database which you want to check if there are **Orphaned Users** for. So which ever database you run it under, it'll tell you only for that database of there are **Orphaned Users**.

They clarify that slightly, just below the example query they provide in the article you linked:

> The output lists the SQL Server authentication users and corresponding
> security identifiers (SID) in the current database that are not linked
> to any SQL Server login.

So if you have 3 databases on your server, for example, then you'd need to run that query 3 times (once in the context of each database) to verify for all of them.

Comment: Actually I tried that on different databases, but it gives empty response. But users are missing in exported database, and they were there in original database. They should be orphaned.

Comment: @Marin So in other words you want to know which databases are missing Users that were in the original database before you exported it?

Comment: I want users and server logins to be as in original database. I just want the system to run after export

Comment: @Marin the Users should export automatically, which is why the **Logins** usually are what are missing and create **Orphaned Users**. If the **Users** didn't export with your database then you have a different issue at hand. How did you export your database?

Answer (score 0):

## SQl Server Logins vs. Database Users

The **master** database contains the SQL Server Logins which can be found in the `[sys].[server_principles]` management view.

A SQL Server Login is then mostly linked to a database user which is stored in the `[database_name].[sys].[database_principles]`  view.

## User Database

A **user database** is any database that is created by the user/dba and which does not belong to the SQL Server instances default/system database:

- master
- model
- msdb
- tempdb
- RessourceDB (hidden)

## Using the Supplied Script

In order to run the script you mentioned you would to this:

```
USE <database_name>
GO
SELECT dp.type_desc, dp.SID, dp.name AS user_name  
FROM sys.database_principals AS dp  
LEFT JOIN sys.server_principals AS sp  
    ON dp.SID = sp.SID  
WHERE sp.SID IS NULL  
    AND authentication_type_desc = 'INSTANCE';
```

In the `USE <database_name>` you would enter the name of your database that you want to check, e.g. `USE AdminDB2`. Or in the Script window you would change the focus from database pull-down window from `master` (default) to the required `<database_name>`.

[image: Screen shot of database selector in SSMS]

If you then run the script in the context of the **user database** then you should receive a list of orphaned users.